# dynamic map points data, the doc.getElementById('id1') returns null in angular

Tags: angular, google-maps

```
var legend = document.getElementById("over_map"); 
console.log(legend);
this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(legend);
```

It renders perfectly when first time the page loads. But when the component gets the data from external link the map reloads and the legend is null. Help !!

Comment: you need to execute it after it's loaded to the DOM

Answer (score -1):

I recomend you not use the DOM with angular, but if you need to, use ViewChild instead of document.getElement

You can access to the child element once the page is loaded, you have to implement AfterViewInit and access in ngAfterViewInit method

Comment: sir, The page is loaded only once. Only the map is updated by clicking buttons. I tried console.log('hey'), but that got fired only once when it got initially loaded and not after the map is dynamically changed !!